# PHP MySQL Class Library with JSON type

Tags: php

I am trying to build an webapp which use vuejs with axios as front end, MySQL as database and PHP as back end. At this moment, i am using my own made php file which will do the database querying.

So is there any PHP library out there that can does the job? Laravel is awesome but i need to pick from the beginning and probably it will be more time consuming.

Try to search google and find out some libraries are great but it does not return the data as json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small API project I use Slim framework [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) with `Medoo` [Medoo](http://medoo.in) for for interacting with the database. Your return response in JSON as well as specify the endpoint. Another tool is swagger that can generate both client and server as well as documentation for your API

Hope this helps.